# Why is my Windows 7 recovery folder 53% of my disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Windows 7 Pro - 64 bit OS - 340gb SSD drive

I'm down to 9% available disk space and looking to stop the bleed and cure the affliction.

I've run disk clean up religiously.

I have only 1 restore point.

My system recovery folder appears to be the culprit and is 188GB which is 53% of the whole drive.

Inside the system recovery folder is a folder named REPAIR which has 2170 files of various size but most are about 250MB and last modified in the last year.

A typical file is 1507676177-reg_0001.inp

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific what location your system recovery folder resides in exactly?  *inp files are not a Microsoft file extension.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: It could be that that System Restore Point is contained in that System Recovery Folder. You could delete it. Still, it should not have become that large in order to occupy 53% of your OffLine Storage Space.

Comment: Where exactly is found your system recovery folder? What is its full path?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai - It could If that’s what the author’s restore point configuration is set to be, although that would be deliberate

Comment: If you have Dell Backup and Recovery installed, uninstall it. Then you might be able to delete this folder.

Comment: @Ramhound, my Maximum Usage for System Restore Points has been (automatically) set to 2%. It is hard to believe that someone has deliberately set it to 53%.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai - I don’t disagree.

Comment: The maximum usage was set to 8% back years ago. I change it to 5% today prior to posting the message.  Dell back up not installed. It was last year but I uninstalled. However, you got me thinking. That the back up worked by creating an image file at that time and then created incremental files of only the changes to the image, not unlike a program named something like DIFFERENCE that I think I remember for the ancient days of DOS.

Comment: Additional information which may have no bearing on the issue. 
I am also using Google Drive Sync for all of my non-system data. C:\ is not included though I am syncing Itunes and a few other data folders on Drive C

Comment: Problem is solved due to harrymc's  and Albin's mention of Dell Backup and Recovery which I do not have in its original manifestation. 

I also noticed that this all started with 60mb files in 2017 and the size progression was damn close to a compounding factor. 

Then I remembered In 2017 Dell said they were switching their backup handling to SOFTTHINKS services, so I quickly looked to see if Softthinks was installed, it was,  I uninstalled it and rebooted and all but 26GB of the used up space in System Recovery was restored. 26gb is my 1 restore point

Comment: Just an FYI if wanting to maintain a backup of Windows, Windows' native method via `ImageX` _(<=Win 7 || `DISM` in >=Win 8)_ is the best and most efficient solution that exists _(ESD compression should be utilized on <=Win8.1, as it's 33% more efficient than WIM)_

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not a standard Windows folder, so was created by some installed product.

Dell Backup and Recovery is often mentioned in that connection.
So, if installed, better uninstall it first before continuing on.
If you never installed it, then check your installed products in
*Control Panel > Programs and Features* for a likely candidate.

Run an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) as administrator and enter the
following commands:

```
c:
cd \
takeown /f "c:\system recovery" /r /d y >out.txt
icacls "c:\system recovery" /reset /T >out2.txt
rmdir /q /s "c:\system recovery"
```

This will delete the folder `C:\System Recovery`, but may cause to malfunction
any product that uses it (if it wasn't uninstalled).

EDIT: Dell Backup and Recovery has now become SOFTTHINKS services.

Comment: Is there any reason why that folder couldn't just be deleted with Shift + Delete instead of using Command Prompt? I couldn't see any mention of the folder being locked.

Comment: @MrEthernet: It's owned by another account and with few permissions.

Comment: Oh I see. Makes sense now. I'm lazy. I would just take ownership, then full control, then Shift Delete.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently this folder belongs to Dell Systems (not Windows!) and is used for it's own system recovery software [see here](https://www.dell.com/community/Tablets-Mobile-Devices/What-is-the-Systems-Recovery-folder/td-p/5056862)

If you don't rely on Dell's system recovery (and use Windows system recovery or some other type of backup), most common solution is to remove (e.g. by uninstalling it though `control panel -> uninstall a program`, but there are [several solutions](http://www.uninstallhelps.com/how-to-uninstall-dell-backup-and-recovery-manager.html)) the recovery software, which will free up the space again.

I would strongly suggest to uninstall it, if it does not work at all, harrymc posted a possible solution on how to get rid of the `System Recovery`-Folder "more directly".